# Sharepoint 2007: best practice to put external database data onto web page

Tags: 2007, web-part

I have Sharepoint 2007 site and have to implement filter (comboboxes) for the list of employees stored in external database.

I can develop web part with asp:DropDownList(s), data access library and asp:Repeater stuff, but don't wanna mess with paging and sorting.  May be it's better to populate standard sharepoint list that will be present under my filters via my DAL ?

How would you implement such a task?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to sharepoint Designer?
Create a page and connect to the external database and go on from there.
Whats your Db sitting on?
Patrick

Comment: Thank you, Patrick. It's SQL server. I'll install SharePoint Designer, it's not installed yet.